# Api Manager Host name may not be null error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using a fresh install of API Manager 1.9.0 on Linux. Per the docs, I set the host in carbon.xml as follows:

```
<!--HostName>localhost</HostName-->

<!--MgtHostName>localhost</MgtHostName-->
```

Localhost is set to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file. When starting up, I get this error:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/wso2am-1.9.0
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,001]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,003]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64, amd64
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,003]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,004]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.7.0_79
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,004]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02,Oracle Corporation
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,004]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /usr/wso2am-1.9.0
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,004]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /usr/wso2am-1.9.0/tmp
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,004]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : root, en-US, US/Eastern
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,076]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,077]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Swap Memory size (MB): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,177]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,198]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,230]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
[2015-07-21 16:45:59,234]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2015-07-21 16:46:01,341]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 51ms
[2015-07-21 16:46:01,500]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2015-07-21 16:46:03,008]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,005]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,510]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering has been disabled
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,756]  WARN - LandingPageWebappDeployer Product landing page not found.
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,757]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,792]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,806]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,811]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,835]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,836]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2015-07-21 16:46:10,837]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
[2015-07-21 16:46:11,140]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2015-07-21 16:46:11,269]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Echo.aar - file:/usr/wso2am-1.9.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar
[2015-07-21 16:46:11,346]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2015-07-21 16:46:11,368]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/usr/wso2am-1.9.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
[2015-07-21 16:46:11,507]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/authenticationendpoint].File[/usr/wso2am-1.9.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint.war]
[2015-07-21 16:46:13,087]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/oauth2].File[/usr/wso2am-1.9.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2.war]
[2015-07-21 16:46:14,019]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2015-07-21 16:46:14,100]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2015-07-21 16:46:14,117]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2015-07-21 16:46:14,139]  WARN - SourceConfiguration Unable to lookup local host name, using 'localhost'
[2015-07-21 16:46:14,142] ERROR - ListenerManager Couldn't initialize the httpstransport listener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
```

Please help...

Comment: Are you using SUSE Linux? If so, you need to map the IP to the hostname in /etc/hosts file as instructed here https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Installing+on+Linux+or+OS+X

Comment: Agreed, it's a dup, adding my server's name to the host file fixed it, thanks